# Order by last of many related records column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

I have a model structure like this:

```cs
public class Company
{ 
    public long Id {get; set;}
    // anower fields
    public List<OrganisationRegData> RegData { get; set; }
}

public class OrganisationRegData
{
    public long Id {get; set;}

    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string ShortName { get; set; }

    // anower fields

    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

So, I need to get a list of companies ordered by last related OrganisationRegDatas shortName field.

In pure SQL, the query looks like this - but how do the same by EF, LINQ and over?

```sql
select * 
from Companies c 
left join OrganisationRegData ord on c.ID = ord.CompanyID
order by ord.ShortName
```

Comment: var companiesOrderedByShortName = context.Companies
            .Include(c => c.RegData)
            .OrderByDescending(c => c.RegData.Max(rd => rd.ShortName))
            .ToList();

Comment: shindetsu, thanks, it`s working!

Comment: nice, i will post as answer so you can accept it as a working solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Your original SQL is invalid, it will produce duplicates.

In LINQ your query should looks like this:

```cs
var query = 
        from c in context.Companies
        from rd in c.RegData
                .OrderByDescending(rd => rd.Id)
                .Take(1)
                .DefaultIfEmpty()
        orderby rd.ShortName
        select c;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var companiesOrderedByShortName = context.Companies
    .OrderBy(c => c.RegData.OrderBy(rd => rd.Id).LastOrDefault().ShortName)
.ToList();
```

In this updated query:

We use LastOrDefault to get the last occurrence of RegData.

Now your list of companies will be ordered by their Regadata short name based on the last occurrence.

Comment: Remove `Include`, it is not needed if you don't want to load `RegData`.

Comment: `LastOrDefault` is not used in your LINQ query, and without `OrderBy` will not work. `OrderByDescending` over `Max` is wrong. Original question is to order by last record in detail.

Comment: You are right Svyatoslav, i edit my answer, what do you think is it looking better now?

Comment: `.OrderByDescending(c => c.RegData.LastOrDefault(rd => rd.Id != null)?.ShortName)` replace with `.OrderBy(c => c.RegData.OrderBy(rd => rd.Id).LastOrDefault().ShortName)`, then probably your query will be right.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = context.Companies
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.RegData.Max(ord => ord.ShortName))
    .ToList();
```

This LINQ query orders the companies by the maximum **ShortName** value among their related **OrganisationRegDatas** in descending order.